# Why does my Power BI card visual have a visual level filter that I cannot remove?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a card visual that I've added to a report. The only other visuals are 3 slicers and a matrix. The slicers are all cleared and the matrix is drilled up all the way.

My card is somehow locked to StoreNumber 1. I haven't set this anywhere and I can't seem to clear it. The card responds to changes in the slicers and matrix, but always filtered by store 1. Help?

[image]

Comment: There's no option to remove or clear the filter when you click/hover over the top right section of the `StoreNumber` filter box?

Comment: Correct, doesn't respond to a hover, left-click, or right click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue (still learning power bi) until I realized that it had to do with the drill down on a report. I could not disable the visual level filter anywhere except on right-clicking on the report and selecting "Drill Up" again.

Comment: Coming back to this, I know I answered it below, but the restart just cleared the drill down I had. This happened to me a few other times and it is indeed tied to other visuals being drilled. It's easy to drill down on a pie graph or bar chart and not realize it is in a drilled state. It'd be nice if the clear button remained and just forced the visuals to drill up automatically, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, restarting Power BI desktop resolved it. This is the second time it has happened to me.

Comment: Same here restarting fixed the issue.

Comment: Hey Eric, restarting fixes it, but only because it clears the drill down on whichever visual gave you the issue. Check the marked answer and it will save you the pain of restarting the whole app if you can identify the visual causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by deleting the hidden filter slicer from the dashboard.

Click the View tab, then select the following:

- Bookmark Pane
- Selection Pane

[image: View tab selections]

Then delete the particular filter slicer from the dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

uncheck the filtered data checkbox in visual level filter

Answer (score -1):

in filter right side there was a eraser symbol.use eraser symbol to remove the filter.[click to view solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsxSj.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of the eraser. This is the crux of the problem. In this case, there is no eraser to click. If you look below, I just marked the answer and added a comment. It has to do with drill levels on chart visuals.